# Problem in integrating Travis-CI with core PHP projects

Tags: continuous-integration, travis-ci, php

I am trying to integrate my project coded in core **PHP**, with **Travis-CI** but it always fails.

Travis reports a failure even when I have only one file in my project.

### PHP file Code :

```
<?php

phpinfo();

?>
```

---

### `.travis.yml` File Code

```
language: php
php:
  - '5.4'
  - '5.5'
  - '5.6'
  - '7.0'
  - '7.1'
  - hhvm
  - nightly
```

Comment: The link to the build report is broken...

Comment: As is, it sounds better suited for software engineering. It is not really related to a devopsy, to one of many tools used but not with a particular target on a devops subject.

Comment: This seems to be on topic to me, as Continuous Integration (CI) is quite important to DevOps.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to write some unit tests and set the `script` variable in your `.travis.yml` to actually run a file.

By default, Travis CI runs the command `phpunit` without any arguments. When this happens, `phpunit` doesn't know what you're asking it to do, and shows a help message, then exits with error code 2 (i.e. **non-zero**, which indicates an error occurred).

The [Beginner's Guide](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/for-beginners) shows you a possible solution of setting the `script` variable to run a `Test.php` file with your tests in (insert this into your `.travis.yml`):

```
script: phpunit Test.php
```

There is an example of a valid `Test.php` in the [example repo](https://github.com/plaindocs/travis-broken-example/blob/master/Test.php) that Travis provides:

```
<?php
    class Test extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
    {
        public function testOnePlusOne() {
            $this->assertEquals(1+1,1);
        }
    }
?>
```